# Script to create swap partition fails when running automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terraform

I am creating a cluster of machines in AWS (Amazon Linux 2) using terraform by utilizing the `user_data` argument under the `aws_instance` resource. Part of the script is the creation of a swap partition. The commands in my script work perfectly if I execute them manually in the instance.

I have tried the following in my script. It creates the partition successfully, but it does not seem to finish up creating the swap as confirmed in `more /proc/swaps`. It successfully executes the lines of code below everything I have showed that I omitted from my post. So it must be failing at the `partprobe`, `mkswap /dev/nvme1n1p2`, or `swapon /dev/nvme1n1p2`. It runs the `echo "/dev/nvme1n1p2 swap swap defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab`. I'm not sure how to tell where it is not executing.

```
# Create SWAP partition
fdisk /dev/nvme1n1 <<EOF
n
p
2

+48G
w
EOF
partprobe
mkswap /dev/nvme1n1p2
swapon /dev/nvme1n1p2
echo "/dev/nvme1n1p2 swap swap defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

The results intended are to create swap partition as confirmed by running `more /proc/swaps`. The partition is created, but not the actual swap.

UPDATE: Here is the contents of the log file:

```
mkswap: cannot open /dev/nvme1n1p2: No such file or directory
swapon: cannot open /dev/nvme1n1p2: No such file or directory
```

However that device is listed when running `lsblk` and the command works if I run it manually.

Comment: Is it showing any errors when it's failing?

Comment: What happens if you run your script under `strace`?  Can you tell what fails then?

Comment: @thatotherguy I am unable to see output when running terraform and the script inside

Comment: @wblakecannon Please log the output to a file somewhere and look at it. Chances are that it's trying to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm getting ```mkswap: cannot open /dev/nvme1n1p2: No such file or directory
swapon: cannot open /dev/nvme1n1p2: No such file or directory``` but that device is there and the command works when running manually.

Comment: please edit your Q with any logfile information that will help diagnose your problem. DON"T add it as a comment please. Good luck.

Comment: @wblakecannon When you test manually, do you run the commands one by one?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes I do.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a race condition with `partprobe`. If you run manually, there will be several seconds between each command so `udev` will have plenty of time to create device node asynchronously. When you run them in a script, it doesn't. You could try adding `sleep 5` after `partprobe`.

Comment: *"I'm not sure how to tell where it is not executing"* - Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: @thatotherguy the sleep fixed it! I suspected a race condition but my co-workers thought of it otherwise. I decided to add a `sleep 10s` after `partprobe`, and I have swap now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from the comments by @thatotherguy:

I'm guessing it's a race condition with `partprobe`. If you run manually, there will be several seconds between each command so `udev` will have plenty of time to create device node asynchronously. When you run them in a script, it doesn't. You could try adding `sleep 5` after `partprobe`.

This solved the OP's error, and I can also report success using this fix.